# Register SQLite user-defined functions with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

I'm developing a Ruby on Rails web application that uses SQLite as the DBMS. Some of our reporting requires some moderately advanced mathematics and so I'd like to define several mathematical functions using the SQLite C API.

According to *The Definitive Guide to SQLite, 2nd Edition* (Section 5.2):

> User-defined extensions must be registered on a connection-by-connection basis as they are stored in program memory. That is, they are not stored in the database, like stored procedures in larger relational database systems. They are stored in your program. When your program or script starts up, it is responsible for registering the desired user-defined extensions for each connection that it intends to use them.

How do I register my functions in Rails? I assume I need to add a few incantations to my database.yml file. Which incantations?

Comment: Just out of curiosity why SQLite if you need to do any sort of reporting? It sounds like using another DBMS like Postgres might be a better fit if you need to grow down the line.

Comment: I agree that an alternative DBMS would be better, but the application is fairly mature and heavily invested in SQLite.

Answer (score 0):

As example, for registering new function 'regexp' with 2 arguments you would need to create file config/initializers/sqlite3_regexp.rb with following content:

```
require 'active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter'

class ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::SQLite3Adapter
  def initialize(db, logger, config)
    super

    db.create_function('regexp', 2) do |func, pattern, expression|
       regexp = Regexp.new(pattern.to_s, Regexp::IGNORECASE)
       if expression.to_s.match(regexp)
         func.result = 1
       else
         func.result = 0
       end
    end
  end
end
```